# PHP strtoupper() vs MySQL UPPER() Performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string-comparison, case-insensitive

When performing a case-insensitive compare of two strings, one string coming from the webpage and another coming from the database, by utilizing (in this case) uppercase transformation functions/methods:

Is it better/faster/etc. to: 
perform the **strtoupper() in PHP** before sending it off into the query for compare?
OR
perform the **UPPER() in SQL** in the query itself?

And does this apply to most functions/methods between PHP & MySQL or is this mostly an isolated case?

Comment: if it's a case-insensitive comparison, then mysql will already be doing `lower(one) = lower(two)` internally anyways. so you'd just be doing work yourself that mysql would already be doing for you.

Comment: sorry thats confusing I guess. what I meant is, I am forcing the case-insensitive compare by performing the upper or lower

Comment: one is probably slightly more efficient than the other, but there's no way to say WHICH is better - depends entirely on your host platform, what libraries/compilers were involved in producing the binaries, etc... in other words, it's such a microscopic difference it's pointless to try and choose one or the other. there's plenty of other better/faster ways of improving your code base.

Comment: is there a "proper" way of doing it or a rule of thumb of sorts?

Comment: not really. mysql by default does case insensitive anyways, unless you set a non-CI collation, or force a `binary` match.

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to measure it, but chances are that any change in execution time will be so small as to be irrelevant to the total run time of your program or web page.  Therefore, choose the method that more clearly shows the intent of what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: I think that everything that is possible to do inside the DB, is better to do inside the DB. they are usually faster than PHP, and what happens if you want to make upperCase to 100k rows?